# Use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution find the probability that Diana got grade C?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Diana took a multiple-choice test of 50 questions and each question carried two marks. The probability that Diana chose the correct answer for a question was three out of four. The marks for grade A, grade B and grade C were 80, 72 and 64, respectively. After the test, Diana was told by her tutor that she did not get grade A. Using normal approximation of the binomial distribution, find the probability that she got grade C?

Does the formla in this case is P(C grade | no A grade) = P(64<= x < 72 | X<80)?

I think it will be something like this, but do binomial distribution support it? or I need to break down into two formlas like find out P(C and B grade | no A grade) then find out P(C grade | C and B grade)?

Comment: Hint: You have the right idea with P(C grade | no A grade) = P(64<= x < 72 | X<80).  Now you need to apply the fact (assuming Diana's chances of success on each question are independent), that $X$ has a binomial distribution with $n=50$ and $p = 3/4$.  Then you can approximate that binomial distribution with a normal distribution and apply conditional probability.